# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable) producing ... results

Tags: json, datatable

I have been using the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert a datatable and upload the outputted json to a website from a winforms app.

The datatable has about 50+ rows in it.

I am seeing results which are quite strange.

Example:

```
 {
    "Itm": "10006",
    "ItmDsc": "Bikini wax",
    "BokLen": 30,
    "OnlineDescription": null,
    "OnlineDetails": null,
    "Cat": "FWX",
    "ItmTyp": "TRT",
    "ItmSts": "A",
    "BokLenEnd": 0,
    "ItmBokCol": null,
    "ItmCrtDte": "2015-09-17T15:42:42.301+10:00"
  },
  {
    "Itm": "10007",
    "ItmDsc": "G-String Wax",
    "BokLen": 30,
    "OnlineDescription": null,
    "OnlineDetails": null,
    "Cat": "FWX",
    "ItmTyp": "TRT",
    "ItmSts": "A",
    "BokLenEnd": 0,
 ...ItmBokCol": null,
    "ItmCrtDte": "2015-09-17T15:46:42.803+10:00"
  }
```

The ... field changes depending on the results being sent and sometimes the ... is within the data.

If uploading the same record on it's own. The result is correct.

I have saved the json to a file instead of using visual studio to view the content its the same result.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you looking at the data? Are you sure that whatever tool you're using to look at it doesn't truncate the long string and add the "..."?

Comment: The above was cut and pasted from Visual Studio (watching the output). It also causing the website to reject the json for the same reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft.Json adds ellipsis (...) at the middle of a serialized array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907196/newtonsoft-json-adds-ellipsis-at-the-middle-of-a-serialized-array)

Comment: I followed that... Still the same issue:
    "Itm": "456",
    "ItmDsc": "Cream ...",

Comment: You actually did the test in the answer, stored the JSON in a file, and it still has an ellipsis when viewed in a normal text editor..? (Not VS)

Comment: Yeah I did..

        Dim jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UploadData, Formatting.Indented)

        File.WriteAllText("JsonNet.json", jsonString )

Comment: What did you view the text file with?

Comment: All right, that is really bizarre then.

Comment: The website rejects the json as invalid which is why we started looking in the first place... very strange

Comment: Sorry My bad!!
the record in question actually had ... in the description. *BLUSH*

Thanks for your help Matti